# How do I prompt the user for input using javascript in Light Tables?

Tags: javascript, lighttable

When using Light Tables to run my JavaScript program, I am trying to prompt the user for input using the "prompt" command. I get the error `Error: prompt() is and will not be supported.` but I know it is possible because there are videos of people using it. I have to use the prompt command. Is there a plugin or extension that I am missing?

```
var subTotal = prompt("Enter a sales sub-total.");
subTotal = parseFloat(subTotal);

var salesTax = prompt("Enter a tax rate.");
salesTax = parseFloat(salesTax);

var grandTotal = subTotal * salesTax; 

alert("Sub-total: " + subTotal + " Sales Tax: " + salesTax + " Grand Total: " + grandTotal );
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/teLS8.jpg

Comment: You will need to include the code you are working with and that reproduces the issue you are talking about in your question. You can't expect people to sit though a YouTube video just to understand your problem

Comment: There's probably a way you can hook into the LT code itself to display a prompt in the newer versions. Make a post to ask about this in [the Google Groups group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/light-table-discussion).

Answer (score 0):

> […the Light Table team didn't explicitly remove `window.prompt` support – it's just a side effect of us migrating from using node-webkit (now NW.js) to Atom shell (now Electron).](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/light-table-discussion/LfssIWhmsXc/QoPyDpP8EwAJ)

cf https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/472

So to answer your question, you would need to downgrade to the 0.7.2 version.